# QT code for U Touch returns `qmlscene: cannot find qt installation of ''`

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt

I'm trying to start developing for Ubuntu and Ubuntu phone, but I get an error:

```
qmlscene: cannot find qt installation of ''
```

when I attempt to run my application in Ubuntu from the command line. I'm very new to Linux, so if you could fully explain what I need to do to fix it, then that'd be great. I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 in a VirtualBox virtual machine on an Asus N56VZ laptop. I installed the Ubuntu SDK using the instructions on http://developer.ubuntu.com, so I really have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance. **Edit your question and include the information asked**.

Comment: But it's not about the code at all. It's about running it. qmlscene is the command to run build and run code. I'm sorry that I didn't make that clearer. Again, the issue is with not being able to build and run my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this by following the [Get Started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) instructions and testing with the [Ubuntu Weather App](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-weather-app). There must be either an error in the instructions or a bug in the Ubuntu SDK packages.

This seems to work as a temporary workaround:

1. Look up the name of your Qt installation:

   ```
   $ qtchooser -list-versions
   qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
   ```
2. Specify the name using when running `qmlscene`, which is just a symlink to [Qt  Chooser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/qtchooser.1.html):

   ```
   $ qmlscene -qt=qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu ubuntu-weather-app.qml
   ```

   [image: qmlscene: weather]

Answer (score 1):

While the above answer is correct in one sense, it's an indication the 'default' configuration has not been installed or is not reachable. qmlscene should work without specifying -qt= option.

The qtchooser listing should show the following on Ubuntu 13.04 for example:

```
$ qtchooser -list-versions
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
default
qt5
```

The following commands should make sure you are up-to-date:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

If those do not help to give the above qtchooser listing, additional debugging would be needed. Above all, the 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' was previously lacking in the official instructions at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ which may have caused problems for Ubuntu 13.04 users.

Comment: It was weird actually, I ran the command in the above answer once, and then I never had to specify the QT version again. I guess it just set it as the default or something.